# Logging program use

Tags: security, logging

I'm trying to find a way of logging what programs other users have been using on the system. I've checked /var/log but don't seem to find anything to show which programs have been accessed. 
I'm looking at historical use, so a ps, top or free isn't viable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel has auditing capabilities.

You can install the packages `auditd` and `system-config-audit` to take advantage of this.

```
sudo apt-get install auditd system-config-audit
```

then to avoid an error you would get later, make a symlink of `/usr/sbin/service` to `/sbin/`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/service /sbin/
```

Then launch the configuration interface:

```
gksu system-config-audit
```

[image]

Go to *Configuration* page

[image]

then click on the button *Edit* near *File watches*

[image]

click on the *Add* button

[image]

then enter the details of the executable you want to monitor, together with an optional distinctive string (just `LS` here), as in the following screenshot

[image]

Press OK, OK, Save and Save.

Now you can see the log of the monitored events with

```
sudo less /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

and you should get an output similar to the following:

```
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1325523963.095:8698): auditd start, ver=1.7.13 format=raw kernel=3.0.0-14-generic auid=4294967295 pid=31838 subj=unconfined  res=success
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325523963.196:35): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325523963.196:36): audit_backlog_limit=320 old=320 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=DAEMON_END msg=audit(1325524792.575:8699): auditd normal halt, sending auid=0 pid=32105 subj= res=success
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1325524792.613:8877): auditd start, ver=1.7.13 format=raw kernel=3.0.0-14-generic auid=4294967295 pid=32115 subj=unconfined  res=success
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524792.712:39): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524792.712:40): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524792.712:41): audit_failure=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524792.716:42): audit_backlog_limit=320 old=320 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524792.716:43): audit_rate_limit=0 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524792.716:44): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="add rule" key="ls" list=4 res=1
type=DAEMON_END msg=audit(1325524929.107:8878): auditd normal halt, sending auid=0 pid=32168 subj= res=success
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1325524929.139:3658): auditd start, ver=1.7.13 format=raw kernel=3.0.0-14-generic auid=4294967295 pid=32178 subj=unconfined  res=success
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524929.241:48): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524929.241:49): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524929.241:50): audit_failure=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524929.241:51): audit_backlog_limit=320 old=320 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524929.241:52): audit_rate_limit=0 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325524929.241:53): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="add rule" key="ls" list=4 res=1
type=DAEMON_END msg=audit(1325525132.140:3659): auditd normal halt, sending auid=0 pid=32407 subj= res=success
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1325525132.173:6001): auditd start, ver=1.7.13 format=raw kernel=3.0.0-14-generic auid=4294967295 pid=32417 subj=unconfined  res=success
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325525132.274:57): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325525132.274:58): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325525132.274:59): audit_failure=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325525132.274:60): audit_backlog_limit=320 old=320 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325525132.278:61): audit_rate_limit=0 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1325525132.278:62): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="add rule" key="ls" list=4 res=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1325525137.354:63): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=2506d48 a1=2500308 a2=249a008 a3=7fffe4130170 items=2 ppid=30147 pid=32431 auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts2 ses=4294967295 comm="ls" exe="/bin/ls" key="ls"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1325525137.354:63): argc=5 a0="ls" a1="--color=auto" a2="--group-directories-first" a3="--time-style=long-iso" a4="--ignore-backups"
type=CWD msg=audit(1325525137.354:63):  cwd="/home/enzotib"
type=PATH msg=audit(1325525137.354:63): item=0 name="/bin/ls" inode=389459 dev=08:02 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00
type=PATH msg=audit(1325525137.354:63): item=1 name=(null) inode=395716 dev=08:02 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00
```

where on the last lines you could see the `ls` invocation a run for test. Ok, the log file is not so simple to read, but with some text processing you can get the output you want.